# Data Science Conferences w/ Poster Sessions?

Tags: bigdata

I am in search of some data science conferences (for 2017) that have a mix of big name speakers and poster sessions.  Ideally, I would like to be able to present a poster that doesn't necessarily have to be a research paper, but simply the development of a tool and its use.

Please provide the name and link.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

KDNuggets has a really nice list of conferences on their page:

http://www.kdnuggets.com/meetings/index.html